# Highlight text inside iframe while clicking same text on the document using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I wanted to highlight text inside iframe if the user clicks the same text outside iframe in the webpage.
I could search for the contents using the below code.
    `$("#iframe").contents().text().search("text_to_be_searched");`
But how to highlight the text?

Answer (score 0):

ASSUMING that your code for finding the text is going to work (and it is going to be a little complicated to get that to work), then all you have to do is this:

```
$("#iframe").contents().text().search("text_to_be_searched").
  wrap("<span class='highlight-me'>");
```

And then use CSS to highlight anything with a class of 'highlight-me'.

If that doesn't work, we'd have to see how you are finding the text, you need to get into the form of a node that jQuery can work with.

Comment: Thanks for the response.But
`$("#iframe").contents().text().search("text_to_be_searched")` returns a number.So that can be used to check if the text exists in the iframe.